# calling two functions on asp.net button onclick

Tags: asp.net

I want to call two functions on button click
I tried like this

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" onclick="tableShow();Unnamed1_Click" Text="Search" 
         Width="63px">
```

Comment: What kind of thing do you want to achieve by doing so? It sounds insane to me. You can call one function then inside of that function you can call other function.

Comment: @Zaksh i want to call 1 more js function to hide/unhide table on the same click.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OnClick is a server side event. Hence you can assign one method and from that method make a call to other method as below.

In asp markup

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" onclick="Unnamed1_Click" 
 Text="Search" Width="63px">
```

In code behind

```
protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.tableShow();
    //Do your actual code here.
}
```

**UPDATE**

If `tableShow` is a javascript method then you can use the below markup

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" 
 OnClientClick="tableShow();" onclick="Unnamed1_Click" Text="Search"
 Width="63px">
```

Comment: it works  exactly i want but as i have no reputation score so i cant vote for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the method inside method to do this.
First do this

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" onclick="Unnamed1_Click" Text="Search" 
         Width="63px">
```

then in code behind

```
protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //call another function here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the `onclientclick` event which allows you to run a JS function w/o a server interaction.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" onclick="btnAdd_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:ResetSaveFlag()"/>
        <asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" OnClientClick="javascript:ResetSaveFlag(); javascript:clearEntries(this)"/>
    </FooterTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" 
            onclick="btnDelete_Click" 
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("partNumber") + "," + Eval("warehouseLocation") %>' 
            UseSubmitBehavior="False"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In the first button (adds a new row to the table), I have a server side `onclick="btnAdd_Click"` as well as a client side `OnClientClick="javascript:ResetSaveFlag()"`.

The second button (clears a row and sets a "clean" flag [so onbeforeunload won't run](http://blog.revathskumar.com/2015/08/javascript-window-onbeforeunload.html)), I'm not using any server side code, just the client side `OnClientClick="javascript:ResetSaveFlag(); javascript:clearEntries(this)"`.  The first one clears the "dirty" flag and the second one clears the row of any entries.

If anyone's interested I can post the clean & dirty flag JS, but it didn't really seem germane to the original question.