# Apply a style with JavaScript and call the click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, code-behind

I have a JavaScript function to change the CSS class of an `li` element. I have placed a link button inside the `li`. I want to make the CSS change using jQuery, as well as trigger a click event on the link button. How would I do this? I have tried many ways but I cannot get both to work together.

This is my function:

```
$(function () {
    $("li").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

My HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs group">
    <li class="active">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onclick="LnkView_Click" 
                ValidationGroup="l">View</asp:LinkButton>
    </li>
    <li>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" onclick="LnkEdit_Click" 
                ValidationGroup="l">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to also call this click event:

```
protected void LnkEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    multiUserdis.SetActiveView(vwViewProfile);
}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964214/calling-two-functions-on-asp-net-button-onclick

Comment: Good editing, @ajp15243 - I approve