# How to make 2 c# functions run on event

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, function, events

I don't know if this is possible or if there is a workaround for this. If there is one I would be very happy.

I have a `<ASP:Dropdownlist>` which looks something like this

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="PaymentMethodRadioButtonList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="PaymentMethodRadioButtonList_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="dnnFormRadioButtons" RepeatLayout="Flow">
    <asp:ListItem resourcekey="NonePaymentMethodListItem" Value="7">None</asp:ListItem>    
    <asp:ListItem resourcekey="CreditCardPaymentMethodListItem" Value="3">Credit Card</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Now I do not have access to the source code of this as it is part of a software module where we don't have access to the source code.

What I'm trying to do is based on the selection that the user makes I am trying to execute a C# function.

So in the HTML file itself I do something like

```
<script language="C#" runat="server">
        void OnPaymentChanged(Object Sender, EventArgs e) {
                     if (PaymentMethodRadioButtonList.SelectedIndex == 2) {

                         //Some CODE
                     }
         }
    </script>
```

Now if I make the `OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnPaymentChanged"` then my code runs. However if I do `OnSelectedIndexChanged="PaymentMethodRadioButtonList_SelectedIndexChanged;OnPaymentChanged"` it does not run both the functions. Is there any way I can run both these functions on change of dropdownlist selected index?

Comment: possible duplicate of [calling two functions on asp.net button onclick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964214/calling-two-functions-on-asp-net-button-onclick)

Comment: Also, this should've been tagged [asp.net] instead of [html].

Comment: Is it possible for you to run "PaymentMethodRadioButtonList_SelectedIndexChanged()" method inside "OnPaymentChanged()". If yes setOnSelectedIndexChanged="OnPaymentChanged()" which internally calls other method.